# SQL transaction rollback and commit

Tags: sql-server, transactions, rollback

I have the below 3 inserts wrapped in a transaction. If any of the inserts fail for any reason I would like the entire transaction rolled back. and if all 3 are successful I would like it commited.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO myTable (myColumns ...) VALUES (myValues ...);
    INSERT INTO myTable (myColumns ...) VALUES (myValues ...);
    INSERT INTO myTable (myColumns ...) VALUES (myValues ...);

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: And what's the problem? What errors do you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `TRY...CATCH`

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO myTable (myColumns ...) VALUES (myValues ...)
    INSERT INTO myTable (myColumns ...) VALUES (myValues ...)
    INSERT INTO myTable (myColumns ...) VALUES (myValues ...)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use XACT_ABORT on to do same trick

```
set XACT_ABORT ON

insert into test
select 1

insert into test
select 1

insert into test
select 1/0
```

All the above statments will be rolled back

Comment: do I need to type anything else? like begin tran ect?

Comment: Xact _abort on will work as long as all are in same batches,if you add go between those ,then those work,You can add try catch no need of transaction